# Would a red giant really help power Atlantis' shields in "The Last Man"?

Tags: stargate, technology, stargate-atlantis

In the *Stargate: Atlantis* episode "The Last Man", Sheppard is transported 40,000 years into the future.  A hologram/computerized version of McKay meets him there with a plan to send Sheppard back to the present.  However, they quickly realize that the star in the system they are in is becoming a red giant.  They have the following exchange:

> McKay: The sun in this system is dying. It's running out of fuel.
>
> Sheppard: Wouldn't that make it colder?
>
> McKay: No. As it consumes the heavier elements, it begins to expand.
>   It's basically turning into a red giant.
>
> Sheppard: OK, so mystery solved. Let's move on.
>
> McKay: No, no. You don't get it. This isn't some kind of cyclical
>   climate change. This is – this is a one-way ticket. This planet is
>   going to get hotter and hotter. Eventually the atmosphere is gonna
>   burn off.

My question is: isn’t Sheppard right?  The reason the a red-giant turns red is that the surface is cooler.  So how could the plan to use the increased solar energy to power the city's shields to protect Sheppard while he’s in stasis work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are correct that the reason a star’s color changes to red is that the surface is cooler (in fact, the surface of a typlical red giant could be as "cool" as 5,000K), the actual energy the star is emitting goes way up.  The reason for this is that the star increases in size so the total luminosity is much higher.  I believe this would yield the increase in power McKay and Sheppard are looking for.  The thermonuclear fusion of hydrogen has moved from the core (where the hydrogen has been used up) to a shell surrounding the core.  The reaction occuring in this shell is what causes the star to expand.  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant),

> Despite the lower energy density of their envelope, red giants are many times more luminous than the Sun because of their great size.  Red-giant branch stars have luminosities about a hundred to several thousand time that of the Sun…

So, in this case, assuming the solar collectors on Atlantis could operate in the severe conditions, there would be more enrgy to collect.  Since we don’t know the operating parameters of the shields, or the exact type of star in this system, we have to assume (since Rodney certainly wouldn't make a mistake) that the increased energy from the star becoming a red giant is sufficient to power the shields at a level necesseary to preserve Atlantis for the extra 100 or so years McKay and Sheppard need.